# Byte array giving different output on replacing string variable

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying to replace some existing logic involving storage in string variable, to use byte array (for security reasons). Following has two blocks method A() with old logic and method B() with the replacement. However, on printing the outputs at similar points, I see different output in case of byte array. Am I missing something?

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Hello World ");
        A();
        B();
     }

     public static void A()
     {
         String expDetails = "";

         if (true) {
            String expYear = "1986";
            expDetails = expYear;
        }
        System.out.println("Output in between "+expDetails);
        // expiry month in MM
        String monthStr = "";
        if (true) {
            String expiryMonth = "12";
            int month = Integer.parseInt(expiryMonth) + 1;
            expDetails += month > 9 ? String.valueOf(month) : "0" + month;
        }

        System.out.println("Output "+expDetails);
     }

     public static void B()
     {
         byte[] expDetailsNew = null;
         if (true) {
            String expYear = "1986";
            expDetailsNew = expYear.getBytes();
            System.out.println("Inside");
        }
        System.out.println("Output in between "+expDetailsNew.toString());
        String monthStr = "";
        if (true) {
            String expiryMonth = "12";
            int month = Integer.parseInt(expiryMonth) + 1;

            if(month>9)
            {
                byte[] c = new byte[expDetailsNew.length + Integer.toString(month).length()];
                System.arraycopy(expDetailsNew, 0, c, 0, expDetailsNew.length);
                System.arraycopy(expDetailsNew, 0, c, expDetailsNew.length, Integer.toString(month).length());

                String finalVal = new String(c);

            System.out.println("Output "+finalVal);
            }

        }

     }

}
```

Following is the output -

```
Hello World 
Output in between 1986
Output 198613
Inside
Output in between [B@6d06d69c
Output 198619
```

**Update**

As per answer by @VGR, tried to append the month value like this -

```
CharBuffer another = CharBuffer.allocate(2); 
new Formatter(another).format("%02d", month); 
expDetailsNew.append(another);
expDetailsNew.flip();
System.out.println("Output "+expDetailsNew.toString());
```

But the output then is empty.

Comment: Why did you make the example so unnecessarily complex? `if(true)` etc.?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The key word here is **minimal**

Comment: I’m not clear on what these “security reasons” are.   This seems like a lot of jumping through hoops just to concatenate strings.  And it apparently is complex enough that it has led to some significant mistakes in your second `arraycopy` call.

Comment: Yeah security by obscurity isn't very secure and just makes the developers life hell

Comment: @RobOhRob I have added more details on the security vulnerability here - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/223934/remediation-for-security-vulnerability-due-to-storing-sensitive-information-in-s. Please check. Thanks

Comment: @VGR  I have added more details on the security vulnerability here - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/223934/remediation-for-security-vulnerability-due-to-storing-sensitive-information-in-s Please check. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.out.println("Output in between "+new String(expDetailsNew));`
above resolve the object reference.

Try change

```
System.arraycopy(expDetailsNew, 0, c, expDetailsNew.length,
```

to

```
System.arraycopy(Integer.toString(month).getBytes(), 0, c, expDetailsNew.length,
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution works, with one correction I did, but could you please elaborate how resolving the object reference helps?

Comment: `[B@6d06d69c` popup just because you are trying to type a byte array. `byte[].toString` cannot help you to see the String. `new String(byte[])` does.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid storing sensitive information in Strings, use `char` arrays.  Don’t convert to bytes using the platform’s default charset;  you risk corrupting the information.  In fact, a number of security-related methods in Java SE already use `char` arrays:

- [KeyStore.getInstance](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/security/KeyStore.html#getInstance%28java.io.File,char[]%29)
- [PBEKeySpec](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/javax/crypto/spec/PBEKeySpec.html#constructor.summary) constructors
- [PasswordCallback.getPassword](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/javax/security/auth/callback/PasswordCallback.html#getPassword%28%29) and [PasswordCallback.setPassword](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/javax/security/auth/callback/PasswordCallback.html#setPassword%28char[]%29)
- [JPasswordField.getPassword](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getPassword%28%29)

While you could use `System.arraycopy`, a [CharBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/CharBuffer.html) is much easier to work with, and it even has a useful [toString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/CharBuffer.html#toString%28%29) method.

Your [original question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/223934/remediation-for-security-vulnerability-due-to-storing-sensitive-information-in-s) shows code which is much clearer than the code in this question, so I shall use code from that:

```
CharBuffer expDetails = CharBuffer.allocate(6);

// extract expiry year in YYYY
if (!CommonUtil.isEmpty(paymentDetails.getExpiryYear())) {
    expDetails.append(paymentDetails.getExpiryYear());
}

// expiry month in MM
if (!CommonUtil.isEmpty(paymentDetails.getExpiryMonth())) {
    int month = Integer.parseInt(paymentDetails.getExpiryMonth()) + 1;
    new Formatter(expDetails).format("%02d", month);
}

expDetails.flip();

reqParams.put("CardNum",
        encrypt(params[4], paymentDetails.getCardNumber()));
reqParams.put("expiryDate", encrypt(params[4], expDetails.toString()));
reqParams.put("CVVNum",
        encrypt(params[4], paymentDetails.getCvvNumber()));
```

As the vulnerability report indicated, String objects are immutable and can be interned, to reduce redundant allocation.  This means malicious code could, theoretically, access String objects used by other objects.  To avoid this possibility and to enforce security on string values, you can alter your `encrypt` method to accept `char[]` arguments instead of Strings.  For example:

```
public byte[] encrypt(String key, char[] sourceValue) {
    Formatter hex = new Formatter(Locale.US);
    for (char c : sourceValue) {
        hex.format("%04x", (int) c);
    }
    return hex.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

(This is just an example, based on your comments;  I don’t know what your `encrypt` method actually does.)

Also, never write an empty `catch` block.  Since this appears to be a web service method, you should just be able remove the try/catch and simply add the necessary exceptions to your method’s `throws` clause.  You don’t really want users to think the application is working when it didn’t actually work, right?

Comment: thanks. Could you please elaborate what do you mean by full security? How is this solution intermediate in terms of security? Could you give some example to elaborate? Also, how do I need to alter the encrypt method, if I need to change it to char[]? Adding details of the encrypt method in the original question as an update.

Comment: The encrypt method accepts string and then calls Hex.fromString() on the value and stores it in a byte[].

Comment: @SandeepanNath Updated answer with example `encrypt` method.

Comment: with your changes, the output comes like this - Hello World 
`Output in between 1986
Output 198613
Output in between 1986
Output 13`. The final output is supposed to be 198613 and not 13. I tried doing the following, but still not able to append - `CharBuffer another = CharBuffer.allocate(2);
       new Formatter(another).format("%02d", month);
                expDetailsNew.append(another);`  Adding details in question update.

Comment: And did you verify that `CommonUtil.isEmpty(paymentDetails.getExpiryYear())` returns false?